# Working with data values (dictionary). dataframes and recoding in R

Tags: r, dictionary, match

I am trying to work with a data.frame that contains 30 or so variables. These variables all have different numeric values (e.g., "0" or "32"). The numeric values map to strings (e.g., in variable Q1, "0" is "Urban"; in variable Q6, "32" is "Not available").

I saw some uses of recode online, and an older `plyr` package that did this mapping, as well as the `match` function, but I didn't find anything that matches the exact structure I have.

I provide a reproducible example below:

```
  test <- as.data.frame(c("1", "2", "3"))
  colnames(test) <- "Q1"
    
  dictionary <- as.data.frame(c("1", "2", "3"))
  dictionary$values <- c("dog", "fish", "cat")
  dictionary$question <- c("Q1", "Q1", "Q1")
  colnames(dictionary)[1] <- "keys"
```

So, here, `dictionary$question` contains the question to map to; and then the "keys" and "values" provide the mapping. So, in the test dataframe, I have one variable (`Q1`) that takes three possible values, "1", "2", or "3". I need to map these back to "dog", "fish", "cat".

But I need an automatic way to map the column in the target dataframe to the rows in the dictionary, and then translate the values, since in practice I have over 1000 possible values and 30 variables.

Edit: what I expect is a function or command that goes like this:

```
fun(test, dictionary)
```

Output: a data.frame with `c("dog", "fish", "cat")`.

Or, if test was `c("1", "1", "1")`, it would be `c("dog", "dog", "dog")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are many columns, loop `across` the 'test' columns, match and replace the values from a named vector created from the `subset` of 'dictionary' where the 'question' matches with the corresponding column name (`cur_column()`) and then use `coalesce` to fill any NA values with original data values

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
test %>%
      mutate(across(everything(), ~ 
     coalesce(deframe(subset(dictionary, question == cur_column(), 
          select= -question))[as.character(.)], as.character(.))))
    Q1
1  dog
2 fish
3  cat
```

Or to prevent multiple calls to `as.character`, do it once

```
test %>%
   mutate(across(everything(), as.character),
          across(everything(), 
           ~coalesce(deframe(subset(dictionary, question == cur_column(), 
          select= -question))[.], .)))
 Q1
1  dog
2 fish
3  cat
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
lst1 <- split(dictionary[-3], dictionary$question)
test[names(lst1)] <- Map(function(x, y) {
    tmp <- with(y,  setNames(values, keys)[as.character(x)])
     tmp[is.na(tmp)] <- x[is.na(tmp)]
     tmp}, test[names(lst1)], lst1)
```

Comment: Hi Akrun, thank you very much for your time. Your solution seems amazing and worked on my test dataframe. However, when using it in my regular dataframe, I come up with the message "Erro: Problem with `mutate()` input `..1`.;
x Can't combine `..1` <character> and `..2` <integer>.;
i Input `..1` is `across(...)`." 

Any idea what might be causing this? I can share some examples to try this out

Comment: @jpugliese i changed it.  I thought about that issue earlier. thanks.  It is just that your original column in 'test' is numeric/integer, so when you do coalesce, it should be one the same type., In the updated one, i changed it with `as.character`

Comment: This worked perfect! Can I test if I understood what is going on? First, we open using across(, as.character), which will turn all columns to character. Then, we apply across again, and this time we run a function. Starting from inside out, we `subset` the dictionary, looking for the row named with our current column (e.g., Q1 here, stored in variable "question").  We select the columns associated with it, but not the "question" itself. We then have a data.frame that contains only those rows. We then deframe it. What's the final coalesce( ,.) doing? And the [.]? Thank you again!

Comment: @jpugliese You are right.  Regarding the last part, it is just to keep the original column value in case you don't have any key/value pair in the dictionary dataset.  Otherwise, it returns NA.  `coalesce` with first argument as the matched one, make sure to return the corresponding first non-NA element for each argument, thus if you have something like `coalesce(c(NA, 'a', 'b'), c('a', NA, 'b'))[1] "a" "a" "b"`