# Subset base function ignoring repeated entries when outputting

Tags: r, dataframe, subset, matching

I recently asked how to use dictionary files to recode values in a dataset ([Working with data values (dictionary). dataframes and recoding in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68475719/working-with-data-values-dictionary-dataframes-and-recoding-in-r))

I am with a simpler problem, but that fix isn't working. Suppose I have the following dataset, each row is a geographical unit, and column V1 lists the "first neighbor" that a geographical package found, ***but lists it using the row number***:

```
V1 <- c(1, 2, 1)
id <- c(110001, 110002, 110003)
dataset <- as.data.frame(matrix(c(id, V1), ncol=2))
colnames(dataset) <- c("id", "V1")
```

So on this dataset, region 110001 is a neighbor of itself (`V1 = 1`), and region 110003 is a neighbor of 110001 (`V1 = 1`).
Now, instead of displaying V1 (first neighbor) as `"1, 2, 1"`, I'd like it to be the `id` of the geographic region, `"110001, 110002, 110001"`.

So, I create a "dictionary" file that contains the rownumber and id of the geographic region:

```
dictionary <- as.data.frame(matrix(c(dataset$id, 1:nrow(dataset)),ncol=2))
colnames(dictionary) <- c("id","row")
```

Then, I try to map these using a mutate. Note that I have many neighborhood variables (V1-V30), and I'm only using one in the example, so I will use syntax that translates to all:

```
new_dataset <- dataset %>% mutate(across(starts_with("V"), ~subset(dictionary, row == cur_column(), select= id)))
```

What this should do is: run across columns, compare values to the values at the rows of the dictionary, and then return the appropriate id. It seems that the problem is the repeated entries in `dataset$V1` (in this example, rows 1 and 3 are equal to "1"). If I proceeded row-by-row, this would work:

```
first_row <- dataset[1,] %>% mutate(V1 = subset(dictionary, row == V1, select= id))    
second_row <- dataset[2,] %>% mutate(V1 = subset(dictionary, row == V1, select= id))  
third_row <- dataset[3,] %>% mutate(V1 = subset(dictionary, row == V1, select= id))
```

My impression is that "subset" is ignoring repeated entries. E.g., if I run this:

```
 subset(dictionary, row == dataset$V1, select= id)
```

It should return `"110001, 110002, 110001"`, but only returns `"110001, 110002"`.

Any ideas on how to make subset return everything or another approach to this?

Comment: Just a hint: `data.frame(id, V1)` is a more convenient way to define that data.frame. You don't need that `matrix()` + `colnames()` way.

Comment: Why is `V1 == 1` replaced by `110001` and not by `110003`?

Comment: Thanks Martin! So, `V1 == 1` maps to the `row == 1` value in dicitonary, which equals `110001`

Comment: @akrun Sorry, I misclicked the solution button instead of the upvote one. I just started testing the solutions before accepting them.

Comment: Yea I thought so lool but cant be too sure online

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `rowwise`

```
library(dplyr)
dataset %>%
     rowwise %>% 
     mutate(V1 = subset(dictionary, row == V1, select= id)$id) %>%
     ungroup
```

-ouptut

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
      id     V1
   <dbl>  <dbl>
1 110001 110001
2 110002 110002
3 110003 110001
```

---

Or with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
 setDT(dataset)[dictionary, V1 := i.id, on = .(V1 = row)]
> dataset
       id     V1
1: 110001 110001
2: 110002 110002
3: 110003 110001
```

---

If there are multiple columns, e.g. 'V1', 'V2', etc.

```
dataset$V2 <- V1[c(1, 3, 2)]
nm1 <- paste0("V", 1:2)
setDT(dataset)
for(nm in nm1) 
   dataset[dictionary, (nm) := i.id, on = setNames("row", nm)][]
```

-output

```
> dataset
       id     V1     V2
1: 110001 110001 110001
2: 110002 110002 110001
3: 110003 110001 110002
```

Comment: That `data.table` solution is simple but awesome.

Comment: The first solution isn't going through in the dataset with many V's. For the second one, making it work for more V's require an apply, but seems to work fine. Only thing though, I didn't want a new column named "newid", so I made a change to: `setDT(neighbors_dataset)[dictionary, V1 := i.id, on = .(V1 = row)]`. Thanks!

Comment: @jpugliese sorry, I thought it is better to update with a new columns

Comment: `apply(neighbors_dataset, 2, function(x) {setDT(neighbors_dataset)[dictionary, x := i.id, on = .(x = row)]})`
  
 Error: `argument specifying columns specify non existing column(s): cols[1]='x' `

I thought apply understood this syntax; how can I the argument pass inside setDT?

Comment: @jpugliese you can't do this with `apply` and data.table as it is looping over the columns, get a vector on which `setDT` is applied which is kind of trying `v1 <- 1:5; setDT(v1)Error in setDT(v1) : 
  Argument 'x' to 'setDT' should be a 'list', 'data.frame' or 'data.table'`

Comment: Any suggestion on how to loop through everything?

Comment: @jpugliese why do you need a loop as this works with `data.table` solution I posted

Comment: @jpugliese did you meant multiple columns

Comment: yes, I simplified in the example but I said "Note that I have many neighborhood variables (V1-V30)"

Answer (score 3):

You could use a self left join with a modified dataset:

```r
library(dplyr)

dataset %>% 
  left_join(
    dataset %>% 
      group_by(V1) %>% 
      slice(1),
    by = "V1") %>% 
  select(-V1)
```

This returns

```r
    id.x   id.y
1 110001 110001
2 110002 110002
3 110003 110001
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a base R option like below?

```
transform(
  dataset,
  V1 = ave(id, V1, FUN = function(x) head(x, 1))
)
```

which gives

```
      id     V1
1 110001 110001
2 110002 110002
3 110003 110001
```